# Why am I unable to print JSON attributes in Python? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, json

I have the following code:

```
jobs = {"24": {"wage": "empty", "phone": "empty", "title": "sapfh", "description": "sod", "time": "twelve"}, "20": {"wage": "987g", "phone": "iudg", "time": "twelve", "description": "fdgsdfg", "title": "sfgji"}, "21": {"wage": "987g", "phone": "iudg", "title": "sfgji", "description": "fdgsdfg", "time": "twelve"}, "22": {"wage": "987g", "phone": "iudg", "time": "twelve", "description": "fdgsdfg", "title": "sfgji"}, "23": {"wage": "987g", "phone": "iudg", "title": "sfgji", "description": "fdgsdfg", "time": "twelve"}, "24": {"wage": "empty", "phone": "empty", "time": "twelve", "description": "sod", "title": "sapfh"}}

for job in jobs:
    print job["title"]
```

But it won't print out the title each time. I just get `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str` but if I put `0` instead of `"title"` it just outputs the first character of the number (so all 2s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you iterate over a dictionary, you iterate over its keys.  This means that your current code is iterating through the keys of `jobs` (which are strings).

You should use [`dict.values`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) instead:

```
for val in jobs.values():
    print val["title"]
```

Now, the code is iterating through the values of `jobs`, which are the dictionaries.

---

If you want to have the keys and the values, you can use [`dict.items`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

```
for key,val in jobs.items():
    print val["title"]
```

Comment: @Aloha64 - Yes.  I actually saw your original comment on Mac's answer so I added the bottom section to my post.  The code will get both the keys and the values.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `for`/`in` to iterate over a dictionary, it iterates over the dictionary's keys. As such, the iteration variable (`job` in this case) will contain each of the dictionary's keys in turn: in this case, it'll contain `"24"`, `"20"`, `"21"`, etc.

You want to iterate over the dictionary values (each of the job dictionaries). You can then retrieve the `title` property of each. To do so, loop like this instead:

```
for job in jobs.values():
    print job["title"]
```

If you want both the keys and values, you can use [iteritems](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) as follows:

```
for job_key, job in jobs.iteritems():
    print "Job key: ", job_key
    print "Job title: ", job["title"] // or jobs[job_key]["title"]
```

Note also that `jobs` is a Python dictionary literal, not JSON (there's actually no JSON involved at all). It's also an illegally formed dictionary literal, since it contains two `"24"` keys (keys must not be duplicated).

Comment: @Aloha64: To get just keys, use `job.keys()` (or simply `jobs`). To get just values, use `jobs.values()`, and to get *both*, use `for key, val in jobs.items()`.